# Perl Data::Dumper output processing

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I am using the `DATA::Dumper` api to parse an html table..

Here is the perl code:

```
print Dumper $row;
```

Here is the output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Info1',
          'Info2',
          'Info3',
        ];
```

Question:
1. I want to modify Info1, Info2, etc before writing into a SQL table. How do i access that from above output?

Something like `$row->{var1}->`? I've tried a couple of options and nothing worked.

Comment: Please read [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perlreftut.html), [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perlref.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perlrdsc.html) - Data::Dumper is not "parsing" anything, it is just showing you the contents of your structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, with an answer that was never selected.

Ways to update an arrayref

- Element by array reference:

  ```
  $row->[0] = 'foo';
  $row->[1] = 'bar';
  $row->[2] = 'baz';
  ```
- List assignment:

  ```
  ($row->[0], $row->[1], $row->[2]) = ('foo','bar','baz');
  ```
- Array list assignment:

  ```
  @{$row} = ('foo','bar','baz');
  ```